# Symfony - Twig - Dynamic variable - How to concatenate two variables in a loop

Tags: symfony, twig, concatenation

I have to concatenate two variables in one, beside the `request.locale`

I explain to you :

I have an Entity named `Lexicon` with several field:
`wordFr`, `wordEn`, `definitionFr`, `definitionEn`

I tried to do something like that for replace the `Fr` or `En` according to the `request.locale` but it doesn't work :

```
             {% set locale = '' %}

             {% if app.request.locale == "fr" %}
                 {% set locale = 'Fr' %}
             {% else %}
                 {% set locale = 'En' %}
             {% endif %}

             {% for wordList in wordsList %}
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{ wordList.word~locale }}</td>
                     <td>{{ wordList.definition~locale }}</td>
                 </tr>
             {% endfor %}
```

How to have `{{ wordList.wordFr }}` or `{{ wordList.wordEn }}` according to the locale  (replace var `locale` by `Fr` or `En`) ? thanks !

In the meanwhile I did this but it's too long and repetitive...

```
                {% if app.request.locale == "fr" %}
                    {% for listeMots in listeMotsLexique %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ wordList.wordFr }}</td>
                            <td>{{ wordList.definitionFr }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    {% for listeMots in listeMotsLexique %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ wordList.wordEn }}</td>
                            <td>{{ wordList.definitionEn }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is to use the Twig `attribute` function which is documented [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html).

It allows you to use dynamic variable names.
You would have to do something like that:

```
{{ attribute(wordList, 'mot'~locale) }}
```

You're basically saying that you want the `'mot'~locale` from the `wordList` object